# jQuery Masonry Non-Traditional Grid

Tags: jquery, css, grid, jquery-masonry

I am having a problem with implementing the jQuery Masonry plugin with a not-so-traditional grid system structure. By "not-so-traditional" I mean it uses a negative left margin on the grid item wrapper (.gw) equal to the gutter of the grid items (.g) to avoid the whole ".last" class problem or having margins on both sides of the grid items (using the awesome "inuit.css" grid system.)

It's hard to describe the problem, it's just items not positioning as they should, the annoying thing is, it works fine in Safari/Opera (for me anyway) but fails miserably on most other modern browsers.

You can check out two versions below, one with no JS at all to demonstrate how the grid works and the other with the jQuery Masonry setup:

No JS: http://test.tomblanchard.co.uk/grid-problem/no-js.html
jQuery Masonry setup: http://test.tomblanchard.co.uk/grid-problem/with-js.html

Any help and/or guidance would be amazing and greatly appreciated,
Thanks a lot,
Tom.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong - looks fine in IE9 - but I don't know what it is suppsoed to look like

Comment: This is how it should look (how it's displayed in Safari): http://test.tomblanchard.co.uk/grid-problem/safari-good.jpg

This is how it's displayed on most browsers: http://test.tomblanchard.co.uk/grid-problem/firefox-bad.jpg

Comment: Turns out it's a problem with having items in the grid adding up to a width of exactly "100%", so instead of having items at a width of "50%" its has to be a fraction less like "45.5%" which I really don't like because I like sticking to a strict grid system all throughout, anyone got any type of solution except this at all?

Comment: All of your links are now 404 errors, I'm trying to do the same thing now on a project without much success.